# Ключевое слово this с++

Tags: c++

```cpp
Myclass(const Myclass& other)
{
    this->Size = other.Size;

    this->arr = new int[other.Size];

    for (int i = 0; i < other.Size; i++)
    {
        this->arr[i] = other.arr[i];
    }
}
```

Возник такой вопрос. В коде реализуется конструктор копирования обьекта .
1) Я не совсем понимаю обязательно  ли всё время писать this-> как в 4, 6 и 10 строках.2)Почему после того, как мы в 4 строке присвоили в Size значение Size из копируемого обьекта, мы не пишем в 6 и 8 строках просто Size, вместо other.Size ?

Comment: Только это не ключевое слово, а за-резервированнное имя указателя на любой объект класса или структуры. _Естественно это касается только самого объекта_.

Comment: @ヒミコ Таки ключевое слово: http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.key

Comment: "Я могу написать мой ответ".  То же самое можно сказать так:  " Могу написать ответ".   По моему второй вариант лучше...

Comment: Это кому как больше нравится. This в конструкторе  копирования встречается часто, чтобы подчеркнуть, где поля старого, где нового объекта. В остальных случаях, обычно используют только если другое имя перекрывает имя поля. Ну или нужно вернуть указатель/ссылку на себя. Но повторюсь, в код стайлах когда использовать this прописано редко, и каждый пишет как больше нравится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не обязательно. Если нет другого имени, например, локальной переменной, которая может скрыть переменные объекта класса, типа

```
Myclass(const Myclass& other)
{

    int Size = 2;

    this->Size = other.Size;  // Тут обязательно из-за наличия int Size выше

    this->arr = new int[other.Size];  // Тут не обязательно
```

По второму вопросу - пишите как хотите. Например

```
int f(int x)
{
    int a = 2;
    int b = a;

    return x*a;
}
```

нет же никаких правил, писать `x*a` или `x*b`? :) Так и здесь - раз это одно и то же значение - используйте, как хотите...

Я бы даже писал так:

```
arr = new int[Size = other.Size];
```

Впрочем, соврал. Потому что раз это *конструктор*, я бы писал

```
Myclass(const Myclass& other):Size(other.Size),arr(new int[other.Size])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < other.Size; i++)
    {
        this->arr[i] = other.arr[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: Как насчет `std::copy_n`? :)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb Да запросто. Только менять - так менять: тогда уж просто использовать вектор...